# JAX-RS 2.0: How to register a Feature or a ContextResolver to have a custom JaxbAnnotationIntrospector introspection registered in the Mapper

Tags: json, jackson, jax-rs, mapper

I have correctly registered JacksonJaxbJsonProvider in my JAX-RS 2.0 application using:

```
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
... classes.add(com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
}
```

Now I need to customise the Mapper it self used in the JAX-RS resources because I need to add SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS.

I have seen examples of how to do this using a Feature or a custom Contextresolver, but I know how to add it to a Mapper I create in my source code but I cannot add it to the Mapper that the REST services use using:

```
classes.add(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);

classes.add(MarshallingFeature.class);
```

Because the JAX-RS 2.0 app ignores those classes.

How can I add the Feature or ContextResolver in my JAX-RS application so they are recognised?

Answer (score 1):

You could reuse the Jersey implementation custom application. [More Info](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#environmenmt.appmodel) And using ContextResolver get the custom ObjectMapper to use.

Example:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
   public MyApplication() {
      /* packages that contains JAX-RS components, registers them to use also */
      packages("org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest");
      /* here register the provider */
      register(MapperProvider.class);
 }
```

}

The MapperProvider Class.

```
@Provider
public class MapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

@Override
public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
   /* you can configure the mapper as you like */
   return new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule()
            .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false));
}
```